# How to use audio effects in API level 7 in android

Tags: android

AudioEffect class was was Added in API Level 9.

Is there **anyway** by which i can implement audio effects in API Level less < 9.

A bit of hint would also be appreciated.

I am developing Application for API Level 7.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) class, it provides a more low level api, that will help you manipulate the stream bytes.